# Citing bibitem leaves a question mark

Tags: bibliographies, citing, document-classes

```
\documentclass{doublecol-new}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\title{IJKL}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
\cite{jojo}


\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{jojo} ABCD
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Above is a minimum working example which compiles, but leaves a ? mark when I try to cite the bibitem. Could anyone please help me fix this.

PS: Link to the cls file: http://www.inderscience.com/www/download/latex-double-column.zip. Unzipping the linked file would provide the cls file.

Comment: @barbara beeton- Well, I have already done that and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The [class](http://www.inderscience.com/www/download/latex-double-column.zip) *completely* redefines the `thebibliography` environment to set a regular list for every `\bibitem`. In fact, there's no citation written to the auxiliary files for use as a `\cite` within the actual document.

Here's a view of the `thebibliography` redefinition:

```
\def\thebibliography#1{%
    \par{\section*{References and Notes}}%
    \list{}{\settowidth\labelwidth{#1}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
    \labelsep 0pt\labelwidth 0pt
    \leftmargin 8pt
     \itemindent-8pt
    \itemsep  5pt
    \def\bibitem{\item \NINE
     \baselineskip10pt plus 0.3pt minus 0.25pt\relax}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
```

Note how `\bibitem` is `\def`ined to be `\item` and there's no indication that content is written to the `.aux` file. Now look at the default definition of `\bibitem` (and friends) from the LaTeX kernel [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co):

```
\def\bibitem{\@ifnextchar[\@lbibitem\@bibitem}
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{\item[\@biblabel{#1}\hfill]\if@filesw
      {\let\protect\noexpand
       \immediate
       \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
       {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
```

It should be obvious from the above that content is `writ`t`en` to the `.aux` file with any call to `\bibitem`.

My assumption is the class is not intended to allow the use of `\cite`. You'll see similar behaviour from the `sample.tex` file, not just in your minimal example. As such, it seems to be *status by design*.

<sub>As a side note, the class is called `doublecol-new`, yet it actually provides `singlecol` through a statement `\ProvidesClass{singlecol}` at the start of `doublecol-new.cls`. This class needs some serious work done to it. I'd suggest not using it.</sub>

Comment: @Werner- Thanks for the clarification. Since the journal paper requires this class to be used, what changes should I make to be able to cite a paper?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to (or *must*) make `\cite` work with the `doublecol-new` document class -- and I'm really not sure that this is even advisable! -- your best bet is to start by commenting out (or deleting) the following code block, which occupies lines 714 thru 728 of the class file:

```
\def\thebibliography#1{%
    \par{\section*{References and Notes}}%
    \list{}{\settowidth\labelwidth{#1}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
    \labelsep 0pt\labelwidth 0pt
    \leftmargin 8pt
     \itemindent-8pt
    \itemsep  5pt
    \def\bibitem{\item \NINE
     \baselineskip10pt plus 0.3pt minus 0.25pt\relax}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}

\def\endthebibliography{\endlist}
```

Next, copy the following (slightly modified) code, obtained from the `article` document class, into the `doublecol-new` class file:

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{References and Notes\HD{0}{0}}%
      %%\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            %%\@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

By "slightly modified", I mean that (a) `\refname` has been changed to `References and Notes\HD{0}{0}` and (b) two instructions have been commented out; see the lines that begin with `%%`.

As @Werner has already noted, the `doublecol-new` document class file looks like it needs *a lot* of serious work. Don't be surprised if you encounter other problems! (E.g., the `abstract` environment doesn't appear to work the way one is used to from, e.g., the `article` class...)

Save the modified document class to, say, `doublecol-mod.cls`. Then, the following version of your MWE should provide a numeric citation call-out.

```
\documentclass{doublecol-mod} % note the modified name
\begin{document}
%%\setcounter{page}{1}  % not needed, is it?
\title{IJKL}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract} % does it even work?
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

A citation: \cite{jojo}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{jojo} ABCD

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick mention: One could include the `thebibliography` update between a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) pair in the preamble. Perhaps that will also be a good indication for the journal that a change has been (needs to be!) done.

Comment: @Werner - Good point! :-) Indeed, one way or another the authors will need to assure that the journal's editorial and support staff needs are unambiguously made aware of the fact that the `thebibliography` environment has been modified in a non-trivial way.